# Get React Element "dir" Value for Display Direction (rtl vs ltr)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***Goal:***

Create a reusable component that detects display direction and renders accordingly.

I'd really like to be able to set dir="rtl" somewhere high in the DOM, then have components inherit that value and use it to determine how to do some processing to display a component optimally.

**Component would be like:**

```
    <div dir="rtl">
      <Field label="This is a rtl field..." />
    </div>
```

**Display would be like:**

```
const Field: React.FunctionComponent<FieldProps> = ({ attributes }) => {
  const divWrapper = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); // A reference to current component...
  const thisComponentDirection = divWrapper.dir;

  return (
    <div>
        <WarpBasedOnDir condition={thisComponentDirection} wrapper={directionWrapper}>
          <MaterialTextField attributes={attributes} />
        </WarpBasedOnDir>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Problem:**

I can't find a version of this that would work:

```
const divWrapper = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); // A reference to current component...
const thisComponentDirection = divWrapper.dir;
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to set the dir on a wrapper element/component then have the React component find the dir from within that component?

Comment: I think using React contexts (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) would probably be a better way that storing an attribute somewhere and trying to use a ref.

Comment: @larz That is one way to go... However I would like to use use the components as an importable library that doesn't need any setup, just parameters.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I think that's still easily accomplished.  You just need to export the context provider and consumer.  Put the provider somewhere pretty high up in your hierarchy and then anywhere you want to see if that's set to `rtl` or `ltr`, import the consumer and wrap the component you're going to use.

Comment: @larz My goal is to not use any framework specific methods outside of the component being brought in from my lib. I'm trying to sever the components dependence on context or props and look at what's already in the DOM of a consumer's application.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough points to comment, I am posting this as an answer.

I think you are looking for react states. Check out https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

If you are using functional component, the `useState` hook can be used

If you are storing 'dir' as an attribute then try

```
divWrapper.getAttribute('dir');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this method, but it looks like the dir attribute isn't found if it is set further up the DOM. Do you know if there is an example of this working?

Comment: const divWrapper = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);  does this code returns the correct reference?